# Inequality (extension of triangular inequality?)

Tags: real-analysis

I am asking help to prove the following statement.

Let $a_i, b_i, c_i\in\mathbb R$.

Statement: $\big[\sum_{i=0}^n(a_i-b_i)^2\big]^\frac{1}{2}+\big[\sum_{i=0}^n(a_i-c_i)^2\big]^\frac{1}{2}>\big[\sum_{i=0}^n(b_i-c_i)^2\big]^\frac{1}{2}$.

In case it helps, I think that, for $n=1$, this is just the statement that the sum of two sides of a triangle is greater than the other side.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is false for $a_i=1,b_i=c_i=0$

Comment: You have your inequality pointing the wrong way. As it stands, it says that the sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle is _less_ than the length of the other side.

Comment: Yes. I need to reverse the inequality. It is a typo. It will be ok in 1 second. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the triangle inequality
$$\|b-a\| + \|a-c\| \geqslant \|b-c\|$$
for the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (because your summation range is $0$ to $n$).

The "$\geqslant$" is needed to include degenerate triangles as well.

Comment: Thanks. Let's see whether I get your idea. Do you mean the following?
 $\big[\sum(b_i-c_i)\big]^\frac{1}{2}=\big[\sum(b_i-a_i+a_i-c_i)\big]^\frac{1}{2}\le\big[\sum(b_i-a_i)+\sum a_i-c_i)\big]^\frac{1}{2}\le$ $\big[\sum(b_i-a_i)\big]^\frac{1}{2}+\big[\sum(a_i-c_i)\big]^\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, that is meant, using the Euclidean norm
$\,\|a\| = \sqrt{\langle a|a\rangle} = \sqrt{\sum_i a_i^2}$

Comment: Many thanks. By they way there was a typo in my comment above. I meant to raise every content in round brackets  to the power of 2, as you probably understood.

Comment: All good, glad it helped ;-)  Frankly spoken, I didn't spot the lacking exponents, guess they have inserted themselves on the track from eye to brain.